# How to get user id from nickname in discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I'm writing a discord bot for my discord-server and the people on the server change their nicknames like their underwear. Can i get the user id from their changing nicknames?

I want to code a command like this:

!command @mention

I need the user id of the mention. Thanks in advance!

Comment: the command should look like this: !command @mention randomValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps :)

```
@client.command()
async def id(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        await ctx.send('Please mention a user')
    else:
        await ctx.send(member.id)
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can just enable 'Developer Mode' in advanced settings of discord, after that you can just right-click on the user and copy the user id.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried the conversion to Member and it worked very well. Thanks again!!

Comment: Glad to help, make sure mark as answer :D